# Push Notification from Firebase using MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, firebase, geolocation, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app is sending in-app notifications. using MySQL Tables and listener. but I want to use Push Notification from Firebase. my DB is MySQL.

I want to send a new order notification as soon as an order is created in the MySQL table.

so order gets created in MySQL, if order created successfully, create the record in firebase.
firebase sends a notification to pizza stores within a 1km radius of our customer.

Can anyone confirm this is possible.??

Is firebase capable of doing this???

Backend API coding is in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible! You can use **Firebase Functions**.

Whenever a record is created in your MYSQL, you can create a record of it in Firestore (see [Firesore API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)) and with Cloud functions **Firestore triggers** (see [Firestore Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)), you may write whatever logic you need (*sending notification to a specific audience in you case*) when a firestore record is created/updated/deleted.

Note: Firebase functions use JavaScript and TypeScript.

Comment: Will it be possible to send notification according to area coordinates?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can write whatever logic you need, in Cloud Functions. But ofcourse for your use case, that is sending notification according to coordinates you would have to maintain records of users with their location and write the logic according to it. Well that's out of scope for this question.